# The relationship between dimension of a manifold and coordinate function

Tags: linear-algebra, manifolds

I am thinking about the intrinsic meaning (what this equation really means) about this equation.

Suppose $\mathcal M$ is a smooth manifold embedded in $\mathcal R^d$, then for any $x \in \mathcal M$,

dim($\mathcal M$) = $\sum_{i=1}^d ||\nabla_\mathcal M \alpha_i (x)||$,

where $\nabla_\mathcal M$ is the gradient on the manifold and $\alpha_i (x)$ is the coordinate function, i.e $\alpha_i (x)=x_i$, where $x=(x_1,...,x_d)$

I know how to prove this but what does it really mean behind this equation? Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What is $\nabla$? What are the $\alpha_i$?

Comment: I just edited the questions. Maybe it's more clear now.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen this before. This is just a special case of the following linear algebra result: Let $V\subset\Bbb R^d$ be a $k$-dimensional subspace, and let $e_1,\dots,e_d$ be any orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^d$. Then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^d \|\text{proj}_V e_i\| = k$. (Here $\text{proj}_V$ is the linear map $\Bbb R^d\to\Bbb R^d$ given by orthogonal projection onto $V$.)

Comment: OK, now that I made that translation into linear algebra, I realize that the result is not correct. Most anything is a counterexample for $d=2$ and $k=1$, and similarly for $d=3$ with $k=1$ or $2$.  Since $\nabla_M$ should be the projection of the usual gradient onto the tangent plane of $M$, I no longer believe the formula in the original question.

Comment: Comment to the OP: If you put *squares* on the lengths, then the proof is just the fact that the transpose of an orthogonal matrix is again orthogonal. Moreover, in that case everything becomes more rotationally invariant, and the result is quite clear if $V$ is spanned by $k$ of our chosen orthonormal basis vectors.